# Unable to display the count down timer in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, countdowntimer

I am using digit count down plugin(url: https://github.com/Reflejo/jquery-countdown) in my rails application. I have placed jquery.countdown.js file in assets/javascript and used //= require jquery.countdown in application.js and have placed the digits.png in assets folder. I am using the following code

```
<body>    
<script>
$('.counter').countdown({
image: "url('/assets/digits.png')",
format: "mm:ss",
endTime: new Date(2014,1,2,18,05),
timerEnd: function() { alert('end!!'); }
});
</script>
<div class="counter"></div>
</body>
```

And application.js code is

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.countdown
//= require_tree .
```

The problem is i am able to get the alert after the countdown ends, but unable to see/load the coundown timer in front end. Can anybody help me to sort out the problem.

Comment: show your application.js

Comment: application.js code added.

Comment: Are you using asset pipelining?

Comment: yes i am using asset pipelining.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me. Put the countdown function inside $(function(){});

That means once the DOM is loaded you are asking jQuery to bind countdown to the div class "counter".

Also, dont specify url() in the images parameter of the countdown function. In fact just paste the digits.png in the public folder and remove the images option from the countdown function. Let the computer work for you!!

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.counter').countdown({
    images: "digits.png",
    format: 'hh:mm:ss',
    endTime: "12:32:55",
    timerEnd: function() { alert('end!!'); }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not worked for me. but it is showing two semi colns. BTW may i know where you have kept .js file and how you referred it in your application.js file.

Comment: Put your countdown js in app/assets/javascripts and remove this line "//= require jquery.countdown" from application.js

Comment: I have tested your approach on sample project (https://github.com/khadarbasha/app_test), in this case it is unable to findout the countdown method because .js file is not loading.  PS: count down timer implemented in index page of product controller.

Comment: I would like to know where i am doing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to require it before `require_tree .`

Comment: Take out turbolinks and see what happens.  If it works after removing turbolinks then you might just need https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

Answer (score 0):

When you use a plugin like this, it's recommended to place it inside `vendor` directory, so in this plugin there is 3 folders : `css`, `img`, and `js`, firstly download these folders then take the files you want inside each folder, for example in js folder there is `jquery.countdown.js` and `jquery.countdown.min.js`, these two files are the same just the second one is compressed and is more convenient  for production use, the first one is not compressed and you can use it in development to have a readable code if you want see how the plugin works..., so use one of them . for `css` there is one file called `media.css`, don't forget to copy images you want which is inside the `img` folder too

second step : place the js file under `/vendor/assets/javascript` and the `media.css` under `vendor/assets/stylesheets`, you can for the moment place the image you need with your media.css or place it as you do under `/assets/images/`, just refer to it using the correct path when you call`$('.counter').countdown()`

the last step is to require your js and css file in application.js and application.css :

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.countdown
//= require_tree .
```

application.css

```
.....
//= require media
....
```

also dont forget to put your script inside $(function(){ // your script }) to be sure that your `$('.counter')` element is loaded before applying `.countdown()` function to it as @beck03076 says